# JVM error when using paperclip to upload large files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, paperclip

I am using rails 3 + paperclip to host my file management app.

However, paperclip seems having trouble handing big files (>= 200 MB)

in the development environment it gives me :

```
JVMDUMP006I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using '/home/ubuntu/upload/Snap.20130322.123321.12125.0001.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to /home/ubuntu/upload/Snap.20130322.123321.12125.0001.trc
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using '/home/ubuntu/upload/heapdump.20130322.123321.12125.0002.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to /home/ubuntu/uploadheapdump.20130322.123321.12125.0002.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/home/ubuntu/upload/javacore.20130322.123321.12125.0003.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /home/ubuntu/upload/javacore.20130322.123321.12125.0003.txt
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".
[2013-03-22 12:33:42] ERROR
```

in production environment, I am deploying this app as a **WAR** file and upload to a tomcat server, it doesn't give me any error but the file uploaded is corrupted.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I modified some tomcat connector config and get this error instead:

```
IOError (Disk quota exceeded): app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:73:in `create'
```

but I'm 100% sure that I have more than enough space to use.

Comment: How are you downloading/uploading the file in code?

Comment: `<%= upload.file_field :package, :accept => "application/x-zip-compressed"%>`

Comment: How much memory is allocated to the JVM?

Comment: I haven't touched it since the beginning, it should be the default value

Comment: Set it as I recommended if you have the physical memory.  `JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"`

Answer (score 1):

> - Some platforms may have broken sendfile support that the build
>     system
>     did not detect, especially if the binaries were built on another box
>     and moved to such a machine with broken sendfile support.
> - On Linux the use of sendfile triggers TCP-checksum offloading bugs
>     on    certain networking cards when using IPv6.
> - With a network-mounted directories (e.g. NFS or SMB), the kernel
>     may be    unable to serve the network file through its own cache.

Add `useSendfile="false"` to the Tomcat connector in `server.xml`

```
<Connector  ...
       useSendfile="false"
/>
```

Other configurations to check

1. Decent memory allocation and timeouts

   ```
   JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
   ```
2. Tomcat Connector options

> **maxPostSize** (104857600 == 100 megabytes, default= 2 megabytes)
>
> The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the
>   container FORM URL parameter parsing. The feature can be disabled by
>   setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not
>   specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes). Two other
>   configurations to check is the timeout limit and the maxFileSizeLimit
>
> **disableUploadTimeout** (make sure its not set to false)
>
> This flag allows the servlet container to use a
>   different, longer connection timeout while a servlet is being
>   executed, which in the end allows either the servlet a longer amount
>   of time to complete its execution, or a longer timeout during data
>   upload. If not specified, this attribute is set to "true".
>
> **maxHttpHeaderSize** (try to double it)
>
> The maximum size of the request and response HTTP header, specified in
>   bytes. If not specified, this attribute is set to 4096 (4 KB)

Comment: I tried add `useSendfile="false"` and `maxPostSize="0"`(unlimited) but it doesn't work, thanks for the answer!